Why all data has to be continuous when using Lavaan for multilevel mediation analysis?
We are conducting a repeated measure experiment with around 40 participants. X has 2 possible values, coded as 1 and 2, representing 2 conditions (so not continuous numeric variable). Within each condition, we have 40 trials. We have two mediators, and each mediators has a range from 1 to 7. Y also has a range from 1 to 7.
I was able to fit in lavaan multilevel mediation model with sem, but the website also suggests that `

If the data is clustered, one way to handle the clustering is to use a
multilevel modeling approach. In the SEM framework, this leads to
multilevel SEM. The multilevel capabilities of lavaan are still
limited, but you can fit a two-level SEM with random intercepts (note:
only when all data is continuous).

What's the logic/reason behind this? Does this mean I should not trust the outcome from the current analysis? If so, is there any other better package I can use? (it seems that "mediation" does not allow multiple mediators).
Thank you so much for any help!!!
Below is my code.
mediation_model <- 
   '       
           level:1
             Y ~ f*X + e*Mediator
             Mediator ~ d*X
           level:2 
             Y ~ c*X + b*Mediator
             Mediator ~ a*X
           
             # indirect effect 
             indirect_btw := a*b
             # total effect
             total_btw := c + indirect_btw
             
             # indirect effect
             indirect_within := d * e
             # total effect
             total_with := f + indirect_within
            
             # calculate covariance
             Y ~~ Mediator
             Mediator ~~ Mediator
             Y ~~ Y
'

mediation_fit <- sem(mediation_model, data = df,estimator="ML",cluster = c("ID"),se = "robust") #
options(digits=10)
summary(mediation_fit, standardized = TRUE,nd=10)

Thank you!!!

You should probably edit your post to include your model code and output, but my guess is lavaan read your X as numerical. However if you had it coded as [0,1], it should work exactly as you wanted. See here

As for your exact question, those features have just not been added to lavaan yet (it's developed by volunteers for free).

Thank you so much for your help nad suggestion! I have incorperated the code in to the post. I coded X as 1 or 2.

I hope you get a response from someone with more experience in lavaan and mediation, but to the best of my understanding, if you code X as 0 and 1, everything should be fine because X is a binary exogenous variable.

I see. Thank you so much for your help!!
